# Запустить OpenTok на сервере

Tags: javascript, php, ubuntu, api, https

Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста.

Пробую запустить OpenTok archiving видео, но с толкнулась с проблемами. 
Не ругайтесь, пожалуйста, первый раз видео подключаю, всю документацию прочитала, видео на ютубе посмотрела.

Установила API на heroku, тут проблем не возникло, всё отлично.(он на https)

Запустила пример из https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/Archiving у себя в PHPStorm и всё было отлично. 
Видео сохранялось и записывалось.

Запускала через `sh run-demo` со всеми параметрами.

Попыталась установить всё на сервер, и тут возникло множество проблем:

- Сначала попробовала запустить так же файл run-demo, но вышла ошибка о том, что видео работает в браузере только на https. Не понимаю, как запустить этот файл на https, подскажите пожалуйста, очень прошу. Там есть строка `php -S мойсайт.ru:8080 -t web`, но тут тоже проблемы. У меня на 443 порт стоит сайт в apache, если я пытаюсь запустить на этот порт 443, то он пишет, что этот порт уже занят. Не понимаю, как мне его на https запустить этот скрипт run-demo.
- Ещё пробовала проверить видео через js. https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Archiving Но при подключении постоянно ошибка CORS:
  `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` Я же не могу на heroky поставить headers Allow cross origin верно?
- Ещё попробовала установить API у себя на сервере, но и тут проблема. Не совсем понимаю, как правильно это сделать без запуска скрипта run-demo, так как он на http запускается, а мне нужно на https. Скачала https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php , прописала в apache2 путь к web/index.php У меня стала открываться такая же страница как и на heroky, но сами методы API не работают =(((

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно правильно это настроить?
Могу любой файл добавить, просто скажите какой.

Помогите, пожалуйста, четвёртый день в слезах.
Писала на en.stackoverflow, но там тоже никто не может помочь

Мой run-demo:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$API_KEY" ] || [ -z "$API_SECRET" ]
then
  export API_KEY=КлючСсайта
  export API_SECRET=СекретныйСсайта
fi

if [ -d "cache" ]
then
  rm -rf cache/
fi

php -S мойсайт.ru:443 -t web
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Настройте в апач проксирование 443 к 8080. гуглится по mod_proxy.
2. Там же в апач, после настройки прокси, в блок VirtualHost можно добавить

   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
3. этот вопрос наверно отпадёт когда заработают первые два